# Object org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpInputStream not of correct type error

Tags: csv, mule, sftp, anypoint-studio

I have setup a sftp endpoint in a Mule batch flow to pull a test.csv file from CrushFTP server I have setup locally on my laptop.

When I deploy the Mule project it deploys successfully but then I see this error message as it repeatedly attempts to pull the csv file:

```
*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* sftpproj                                      * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************

INFO  2016-09-29 10:43:34,241 [[sftpproj].SFTP.receiver.01] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Created instance 30388390-8629-11e6-a2c5-1e6f20524153 for batch job sftpprojBatch
INFO  2016-09-29 10:43:34,243 [[sftpproj].SFTP.receiver.01] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Starting input phase
INFO  2016-09-29 10:43:34,245 [[sftpproj].SFTP.receiver.01] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Input phase completed
ERROR 2016-09-29 10:43:34,281 [[sftpproj].SFTP.receiver.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Object "org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpInputStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
Type                  : com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Object "org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpInputStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy:64 (null)
2. Object "org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpInputStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) (com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException)
  com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine:378 (null)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object "org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpInputStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}"
    at org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:64)
    at org.mule.util.collection.EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.split(EventToMessageSequenceSplittingStrategy.java:25)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader.splitAndLoad(BatchQueueLoader.java:63)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine.load(DefaultBatchEngine.java:361)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchJob.execute(DefaultBatchJob.java:305)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchJob$1.process(DefaultBatchJob.java:229)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:511)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:226)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:208)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:200)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:187)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver$1.process(SftpMessageReceiver.java:203)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver$1.process(SftpMessageReceiver.java:179)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver.routeFile(SftpMessageReceiver.java:178)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver.poll(SftpMessageReceiver.java:121)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:216)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:80)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:49)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

********************************************************************************
```

It looks as though the datatype is incorrect but not sure how I can change this as I cannot put a transform connector between the sftp endpoint and the sftp server.  I have set the MIME type to application/csv in the Advanced tab of the sftp endpoint but the error message still persists.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp" xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd">
    <sftp:connector name="SFTP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SFTP"/>
    <batch:job name="orderexperienceBatch">
        <batch:input>
            <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP" host="localhost" port="2222" path="//" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="SFTP"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
</mule>
```

CSV file:

```
1,test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not the issue with your CSV or Configuration. Actually `batch:input` should generate iterable data. Put following DWL and it will work fine.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like it has resolved that error but now receiving this error: ERROR 2016-09-29 12:13:46,804 [[orderexperience].SFTP.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageReceiver: Error in poll
java.io.IOException: 3: %DELE-bad%